# Clearly explicating the relationship of boolean operators to one another (part 2)

Tags: sheffer-stroke, functional-completeness, boolean-algebra, posts-lattice

Follow up from part 1, this question: [What is the relationship between the logical operators in a logic, and how can that relationship be generalized?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/110932/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-logical-operators-in-a-logic-and-how-can-t)

From an abstract algebraic perspective, we are looking at binary operations / binary laws of composition, on a two-element set {0, 1}.

"Functional completeness" is defined as an operator that can "express all possible truth tables". Well, from the perspective of abstract algebra, what is a "truth table"? A truth table is just an operation - defined by the output it assigns to the inputs. We can define a new operator in terms of pre-existing operators, like @: B x B -> B, where @(b1, b2) = b1 * (b1 * b1).

Maybe we can spell this out simply by choosing just one possible path of constructing new operators from old. Let's use the Sheffer stroke. I'll denote it #.

What are the most minimal new operations you can define, from your current one?

You can say, %(b1, b2) = #(b1, b2) (trivial definition; identity).

Next, %(b1, b2) = #(b1, b1), and %(b1, b2) = #(b2, b2). These operations are equivalent to NOT-B1 and NOT-B2.

Next, %(b1, b2) = #(b1, #(b1, b2)), %(b1, b2) = #(#(b1, b2), b2), etc. Combinatorially, I think what we have here is actually an inductive (or "co-inductive"?) type, enumerated by a few possible constructors/constructive axioms -

```
term0 := #(b1, b2)
SWAP-RIGHT(term) := term(term_argleft, term_argleft)
SWAP-LEFT(term) := term(term_argright, term_argright)
RECURSE-LEFT(term) := term(term(term_argleft, term_argright), term_argright)
RECURSE-RIGHT(term) := term(term_argleft, term(term_argleft, term_argright))
```

I don't think this formalism is ready to be used, but I hope you can see where my thinking is headed.

I need a language to express possible modifications of the sheffer stroke, so I can express the relationship between different binary operations themselves, functionally - i.e., NAND-squared = _____? NAND-(substitute left) = NOT-B1. etc.

This is only a tiny hint at what I am trying to get at. I believe it is leading up to Post's lattice, but I haven't grasped the core concepts yet in order to arrive there yet. If someone can show how this leads there step by step, that could help me. Thanks

Comment: As well as [Post's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice) you may find the concept of the [Zhegalkin polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhegalkin_polynomial) useful.

Comment: At risk of starting from an obvious place, have you read the SEP article on the Mathematics of Boolean Algebra? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boolalg-math/

Comment: Search for NAND and NOR on Wiki. There you can find the formulas for expressing NOT and OR, and so on.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a context-free grammar and its resulting grammar trees? Your "axioms" already look much like a Backus-Noir form.

Comment: @aschepler Guess the other guy is called naur https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Answer (score 2):

Since Boole there has been a lot of development of the theory of boolean algebra (for a brief history I'll point you in the direction of the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on [The Algebra of Logic Tradition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/)), but one of the most interesting and relevant discoveries comes from Marshall Stone, who proved a [Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) for boolean algebras in a particular class of topological spaces:

> every Boolean algebra B is isomorphic to the algebra of clopen subsets
> of its Stone space S(B).

Once you've proved this quality about Boolean Algebras, the idea that "And"/"Or"/"Not" start to look very like "Intersection"/"Union"/"Complement" is no longer just an interesting observation but is in fact mechanically foundational to the application of algebraic methods across various fields to the operation of logical deductions - from here you get Model theory, you get to use lattice and ring theories in understanding variations in the behaviours of different kinds of functional connectives and how weaker or stronger logics can be translated into different kinds of set topologies or types.

One interesting quality of Stone spaces is that they are Hausdorff spaces - the foundational points, the basis parts (i.e. the bits that get T and F) of the basic algebra, are separated by neighbourhoods, such that there's no intersection between the points at the building blocks of the algebraic interpretation.  This is an important quality in what it takes to understand the operations of the Boolean Truth Table - there are no "both" values, there are no "part T part F" values.

So one proposal for why the NAND gate has this kind of universality to it is to say that it reflects this separation property of underlying set topology - that no basis points get both truth values at the same time.  To say that A NAND B is true is simply to say that the neighbourhoods of A and B are exclusive.  Because this is a foundational quality of the model theory, using NAND to build up your logic **is basically modelling** by specifying that A and B are distinct.

What about NOR? Well, another property of the Stone space is that the topology is Compact - its valuations are closed and bounded, there are no holes or gaps in the topology either in the middle or at its boundaries.  By noting that we want A NOR B to be true, we're talking about something that isn't accounted for by either of A or B - again, **we're modelling** by identifying a new (? potentially previously unnamed!) point in the topology that is distinct from either A or B that, thanks to the Compactness property, has to exist.

So I guess the moral I'm trying to impart with this is that the model theory of boolean algebra actually lends a lot of the theoretical clarity that I think you're trying to do purely formalistically.  You'll find your way to the theories of algebraic structures by looking at what you get from the representational interpretation in the domain of sets, and this, in turn, gives you lots of tools and reasons to think that some other sense might be made of different kinds of structure and algebras of logic.

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but the reason I'm putting it here is to try to nudge you in the direction of what I think are some really important core concepts in all of this that will save you a lot of scrambling in the dark!

Comment: This is a beautiufl answer, totally expanding the territory of my awareness. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that is a suitable answer as I'm still unsure what you try to do here. Like do you want to construct some kind of language parser? A [Backus-Naur-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) of those?

Something like:

```
Start ::= EXPR
EXPR ::= OPERAND NAND OPERAND
OPERAND ::= EXPR | TERMINAL
TERMINAL ::= A|B
```

Where you start with an `EXPR(ESSION)` that can be replaced by `OPERAND NAND OPERAND` where each of the `OPERAND`s can be replaced by either A new `EXPRESSION` or one of the 2 `TERMINAL(CHARACTER)`s.  Or another attempt:

```
Start ::= EXPR
EXPR ::= TERMINAL |  (EXPR) NAND (EXPR)
TERMINAL ::= A NAND A| A NAND B
```

As you might be uncomfortably with A, B appearing singular without the `NAND`. Might also add `B NAND B` as TERMINAL, but it's just `A NAND A` with a different name.

Disclaimer: That is just Pseudocode to showcase the idea, look into the specifics as to whether that works like this.

That should let you construct any possible operator, but it doesn't really give you any insight into how and why these operators correlate.

Or do you mean something like

```
NOT(A) ::= A NAND A
NAND(A,B) ::= A NAND B
AND(A,B) ::= NOT(NAND(A,B))
OR(A,B) ::= NAND(NOT(A), NOT(B))
IMPL(A,B) ::= OR(NOT(A), B)
```

But that's just one way of doing it, you could also define the implication via `NAND(A, NOT(B))`. Also for example `NOT(NOT(A))` could be expanded to `NOT(A NAND A)` or `NOT(NAND(A,A)` which is the same as `AND(A,A)` which is (if you compute the truth table) the same as `A`. So you'd need to be able to use these substitutions in both directions.

Also if you just generate these operators with the parsers above you'd get a complete set of them, but you're also getting lots of definitions of these operators that overlap or are needlessly complex, don't you? While you would not get a good description of their relation to each other, are you?

Comment: That's a really nice answer, I'll come back to process it more fully and respond. Thank you!